# Sometimes Vim starts ignoring mappings on Ctrl-keys

Tags: vim, ssh, terminal, tmux

Lately, when using Vim in tmux over ssh, sometimes something happens where Vim starts ignoring all my mappings that start with Ctrl: for instance `<C-P>`, which I have bound to the CtrlP plugin. Instead, Vim runs the builtin action (in this case, moving lines upward in the file). I don't doubt that the correct keypress is *reaching* Vim, as it uses the correct builtin action associated with `<C-P>` (using `:send-keys` to send `ctrl-p` from tmux also causes the builtin `<C-P>` in vim to run, instead of the mapping).

All my mappings not involving the control key still work. For instance, I can do this:

`nnoremap p :echo "test"<cr>`, and pressing `p` echoes `test`

But then immediately after,
`nnoremap <c-p> :echo "test"<cr>`, and pressing `CTRL-P` doesn't echo test, it moves the cursor up one line.

Restarting Vim always fixes the issue, but at some point, something I do causes the problem to surface again. I've been working mostly in tmux through ssh lately, so I'm not 100% sure if either one of those are the problem (although I think I recall this happening once in Vim in tmux *not* over ssh), but as mentioned above, I believe using send-keys directly from tmux as a test is ensuring that vim is getting the actual `ctrl-p` keycode. As well, `<C-V><C-P>` in insert mode does actually insert `^P`.

Note that although I've used `ctrl-p` here as an example, since it's a key I actually use a lot in practice, this applies to any control key mapping.

Is there some kind of Vim state I don't know about that's causing this to happen? Is this likely a terminal problem? What are my next steps?

Comment: Your notation is a bit inconsistent. Are you pressing `Control+p` or `Control+Shift+p`? Also, if you are confident Vim receives `^P`, then the problem is elsewhere. Anyway, this question has nothing to do with programming so it should be moved to a more appropriate place, like the Tmux's issue tracker or Superuser. Just make sure you try some more stuff on your end: does it work as expected with local Vim? with local Vim via local tmux? with remote Vim through SSH? with remote Vim through SSH via local tmux? with remote Vim via remote tmux through SSH?

Comment: What does: `:verbose map <c-p>` do?
Also you must be sure that `echo &cpoptions` does not show `<`.